# Svelte: Using reactive input in <script>

Tags: svelte

I am looking to use a reactive value to filter an array used in a chart. I tried both a `bind:value` and `on:change` approach. Both succeeded in outputting the index needed, but I am trying to use that value upstream in the `<script>` because there is a lot of processing of that data once the correct array index is selected.

Is there any way to use a reactive value in the script?

```html
<script>
    let arrayIndex = 1; 
    let data_1 = { count: "a" };
    let data_2 = { count: "b" };

    let data_agg = [data_1, data_2];
    let data_filter = data_agg[arrayIndex];
</script>

<h1>Filter</h1>
<select bind:value={arrayIndex}>
    <option value={0}>0</option>
    <option value={1}>1</option>
</select>

<h1>Array Index</h1>
{arrayIndex}

<h1>Filtered Data</h1>
{Object.values(data_filter)}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/93e9c1e371cf49c0a489db365869bee1?version=3.48.0)

Changing the value below "Filtered Data" is basically what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `let`/`const` declarations with `$:` to make them reactive, in this case:

```js
$: data_filter = data_agg[arrayIndex]
```

This makes sure that the value is updated if either `data_agg` or `arrayIndex` is changed.

Top level values depending on reactive values should also be reactive, e.g.

```js
$: data_filter = data_agg[arrayIndex];
$: data_mapped = data_filter.map(x => ...);
```

If only the end result is needed in e.g. the HTML template or event handlers, reactive statements can be combined into blocks or functions. For the above example this could be done:

```js
$: data_mapped = (() => {
  const data_filter = data_agg[arrayIndex];
  return data_filter.map(x => ...);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to then use data_filter in the script. This REPL is a better example of what I was trying to ask: Thanks for the response, I should have been more clear. The downstream filtering is better shown by this example: https://svelte.dev/repl/87ef5280dd154988a627d2f4e4f2bf9a?version=3.46.2

What you answered solves the example I provided perfectly, but I am trying to then use that updated data as index filter and process the data more. Hopefully the new REPL explains the problem better.

Comment: EDITING COMMENT: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to then use data_filter in the script. This REPL is a better example of what I was trying to ask: https://svelte.dev/repl/87ef5280dd154988a627d2f4e4f2bf9a?version=3.46.2

What you answered solves the example I provided perfectly, but I am trying to then use that updated data as index filter and process the data more. Hopefully the new REPL explains the problem better.

Comment: @user15167046: Reduce the code to a minimal reproducible example and ask a separate question. Find the source of the problem, isolate it. I will not read through heaps of superfluous code. `data_filter` can be used like any other read-only variable in the script.

Comment: Thanks again @H.B. Here is that example stripped down: https://svelte.dev/repl/93e9c1e371cf49c0a489db365869bee1?version=3.48.0

//  let data = data_preprocess[0]; // This runs
 $: data = data_preprocess[arrayIndex] // This does not

The key part of the code is above, lines 12 and 13. I find that that reactive value cannot be used like any other variable in the script.

Comment: @user15167046 Check the following values if they depend on the reactive one and so need to be reactive as well - have a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/480f96c732c0455aa67eaacae802f6b3?version=3.48.0) with comments

Comment: @user15167046 What Corrl stated is correct. You can pretty much always consider it a mistake to have something reactive but then trying to set top level constant values depending on that. So my statement was inaccurate as you cannot do that due to the statement ordering performed by Svelte. Reactive values can be used in event handlers though, as those usually run much later. Your code should probably simplified to reduce the number of reactive statements to just outputting the values you actually need in the end. You can either use reactive blocks or call functions reactively to do this.

Comment: @user15167046 Example using reactive immediately invoked function to generate the `series`: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/50979354bb0a445b9856376f19d90783?version=3.48.0). Edited answer to give an example there as well.

Comment: Thanks @Corrl and @H.B.! I really appreciate the detailed comments and help! Both of these answers are tremendously helpful!